# Jupyterhub - import data from another file

Tags: python, import, jupyter, jupyterhub

I am new to jupyterhub, and I'm trying to do the following. 
So have a code on jupyterhub, that is supposed to do the following:

```
from a import b
```

where `a` is another file in the same "Folder". However, it's not working as it usually works on Spyder, and I'm receiving the following error message:

`ImportError: No module named 'a'`

How could I import data or functions from another files on jupyterhub?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this.
Simply I create the module on `Spyder`, and saved it as `a.py`, then uploaded it to JupyterHub.

Then from the original source code I did

`from a import b`

and it worked correctly.